# How to solve this system of non-linear equations of second order?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I have a system of three equations:

$$a_1- (b_1x+cx^2-cx) + (dx - x^2 + x) - yz = 0 $$
$$a_2- (b_2x+cx^2-cx) + (dx - x^2 + x) - (y+1)z = 0 $$
$$a_3- (b_3x+cx^2-cx) + (dx - x^2 + x) - (y+2)z = 0 $$

All coefficients $a,b,c,d$ are given (real numbers). The variables are $x,y,z$.

Does this system make sense and if so, how can it be solved over real numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Subract the first from the second : $y$ disappears; subract the second from the third and no more $y$.

So, you are left with two linear equations in $x$ and $z$; solve them (it is simple).

When you have the solution, use the first to get $y$.

Comment: You mean no more $x^2$? Or rather no more $y$ or $x^2$.

Comment: If you do what I suggested, all terms in $x^2$ and all terms in $y$ are gone.

Comment: Indeed :) Looks promising, let me do this.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @plktrautman. You are very welcome ! Simple, isn't it ? Take care : you could have a serious problem if $b_1-2b_2+b_3=0$

Comment: Unfortunately that's the case - the equations "disappear". I guess that means one is linear combination of the other one (identity). ?